# Dual-Boot with Mac OS Catalina - Outdated Info on Installation and Disk Partition

Tags: dual-boot, macbook, disk-management

Things are really messy now with Catalina... the many disks and divisions Apple made in the disk are quite confusing. Anyhow, I want to dual-boot elementary OS but I haven't been able to partition the disk in the terminal - all the info I was able to find was outdated and didn't portray the actual steps needed with Catalina. There is the option to do it in Disk Utility also, but there it shows the options of format: APFS, Mac OS Extended, MS-DOS, and ExFAT.

Which one should I choose? Or does anyone know how to do it in the terminal directly with `$ diskutility` ? My problem in the terminal lies in determining the disk, its name and which one to use. I have tried the huge UUID and also the path, e.g. /dev/disk1 - and neither one has worked. It says:

"does not appear to be a valid Core Storage Logical Volume UUID or disk"

Please help, it's been almost a week that I'm being knocked out by this lol